# Array result keep getting the last result

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I put a partial of my code which I think is the source of problem but I could not figure out hence why I am at StackOverFlow now. Anyways this Class is where i set my data and pass it into an array.

```
public ArrayList<select.rates> caseGetRates() throws RateTableException, SessionDisconnectedException {

    try {
        for(int i=0;i < arrayRate.size();i++){
             ArrayList<select.rates> arr = new ArrayList<select.rates>();
             this.setPair(array[0]);
             this.setBid((array[2]));
             this.setAsk((array[3]));
             arr.add(this);
        }
        return arr;
      } finally{}
 }
```

When I `System.out.print` the data which I set in this class it gives me:

```
EUR/USD
1.12372
1.12384

USD/JPY
100.622
100.641
```

which is correct and what I would like it to be displayed on my webpage.However when I pass the data to my `Servlet`

```
try {
    ArrayList<select.rates> rates = example.caseGetRates();

    for(int i=0;i < rates.size();i++){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(rates.get(i).getPair());
        System.out.println(rates.get(i).getBid());
        System.out.println(rates.get(i).getAsk());
    }
    request.setAttribute("rates", rates);
} 
request.getRequestDispatcher("/NewFile.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The result I get on my Servlet is:

```
USD/JPY
100.622
100.641

USD/JPY
100.622
100.641
```

The result does loop twice however the data seems to be overwritten and I still can't figure out why is this happening. I hope someone can pin point my mistake.

Comment: You modify the same object (``this``)and then add it multiple times using ``arr.add(this);``.

Comment: Check the scope of arr local variable. It should be outside the for loop so you can return it. Also create new object of this, set it and add to the Arraylist.

Comment: You start by stepping back and learning about the essential basics of Java. Like what happens when you add the **same** object to some collection over and over again. Dont overburden yourself with JSP and servlets when you dont even understand what happens when you use *this* the way you do.

Comment: Thx guys for the reply.I know I should not using <b>this</b> but I done both methods creating a new object outside the loop and using this.Both method could not work.And also putting the variable also the loop also not working.Hence why am asking help lol...

Answer (score 0):

Create `ArrayList` object outside for loop

and inside for loop create new Object that you are adding to ArrayList

```
try {
    ArrayList<select.rates> rates = example.caseGetRates();

    for(int i=0;i < rates.size();i++){
        // create new object here and then add to ArrayList
    }
    request.setAttribute("rates", rates);
} 
  request.getRequestDispatcher("/NewFile.jsp").forward(request, response);
```